# UISearchController table view results empty

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisearchcontroller, is-empty

I have been struggling a lot with this problem. Some posts deal with this problem but no solution has emerged in my case.

Here is the problem: I would like to display some results with the UISearchController method. My original table view with a custom cell works perfectly in the sense that all my entries are here and it displays as I want.

When I'm using a search bar with scope buttons, again everything is working perfectly, my filtered results are correctly stored in a list and even my custom cell get everything it needs, in the sense that when I check the cell attributes, it corresponds to the filtered entries...

But where I go crazy is that the "new" table view (the one with the results) that is displayed is empty (in the sense that all the view is filled with empty lines) despite the fact the filtered entries are here and that the cellForRowAtIndexPath is doing its job (at least until it has to become displayed).

Could someone help me to sort this out?

The code:

```
- (void)updateSearchResultsForSearchController:(UISearchController *)searchController {

    NSPredicate *predicate;

    NSString *searchText = searchController.searchBar.text;
    NSInteger scope = searchController.searchBar.selectedScopeButtonIndex;

    if (scope == 0) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.drugName contains[c] %@", searchText];

    }

    if (scope == 1) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.marque contains[c] %@", searchText];

    }

    else if (scope == 2) {
        predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF.classFamily contains[c] %@", searchText];

    }

    NSMutableArray *tempArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[[SubstrateStore sharedStore] allSubstrates] filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate]];
    self.filteredResults = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:tempArray];

    [self.tableView reloadData]; // -> I tried to remove, to change the table view, etc, it does change anything
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    TableViewCell *cell = (TableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Substrate *substrate = self.products[indexPath.row];

    if (_searchController.active && ![_searchController.searchBar.text isEqualToString:@""]) {

        substrate = self.filteredResults[indexPath.row];
    }

    [self configureCell:cell forProduct:substrate]; // when I check cell attributes (drugName,...), they are there...

    return cell; // it works when no search is done (with the native table view) but the cell is not displayed when using the search bar (empty table view)
}
```

I you need more code...

Thanks!

Comment: 1. Are you sure that `tempArray` has any object?. 2. Are you sure that `self.filteredResults` is the correct dataSource of `self.tableView`? 3. When you invoke `[self.tableView reloadData]`, any of `UITableViewDelegate` method is invoked?

Comment: the proble was I forgot to set the datasource to self for the results tableview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you are reloading self.tableView and not the searchController's tableView.

Make sure that you also properly assign the dataSource and delegate of the searchController's tableView to self.

Comment: It was something I read before but even when trying to reload the filtered table view it does not seem to work. Or I should probably be mistaken in the way to do it. Should I reload Data in the same place?

Comment: Because I have read that the same tableview is used to display the results with this method. How could it be possible to reload the searchController's table view? I am not sure I create an other tableview

Comment: You have two tables, it sounds. You have the main table on your VC, which is properly updating because your'e calling `[self.tableView reload];`, and you have the tableView that exists on the searchController. I think it might be under searchController.searchResults or something similar. set a breakpoint in that method and check your memory stack to find the exact value. Your searchController has a reference to the blank table being displayed, and you're never updating the data for that table, so it stays blank. Make sure you assign the delegate/datasource to self for results table view.

Comment: Even trying with [self.resultsTableController.tableView reloadData]; it does not seem to help...

Comment: Are you sure that is the correct reference path to the tableView? I can't verify that.  Make sure that when you initialize the searchController that you set it's tableView datasource and delegate to self, so that it uses the same `CellForRowAtIndexPath:` call that is properly setting up your other tableView.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I forgot to set the datasource to self in the viewDidLoad method... Only the tableView delegate was set. Thanks!! How can I mark your last answer?

Comment: @Trichophyton glad I could help. I've updated my answer to include the info that solved this. You can't mark a comment as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.products = [[SubstrateStore sharedStore] allSubstrates];
    self.filteredResults = [[NSArray alloc] init];

    self.tableView.tableFooterView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    // SearchBar
    _resultsTableController = [[ResultsTableViewController alloc] init];
    _searchController = [[UISearchController alloc] initWithSearchResultsController:self.resultsTableController];
    self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self;
    [self.searchController.searchBar sizeToFit];
    self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar;
    self.searchController.searchBar.showsScopeBar = YES;
    self.searchController.searchBar.scopeButtonTitles = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"DCI", @"Nom de marque", @"Classe", nil];

    // we want to be the delegate for our filtered table so didSelectRowAtIndexPath is called for both tables
    self.resultsTableController.tableView.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.delegate = self;
    self.searchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = NO; // default is YES
    self.searchController.searchBar.delegate = self; // so we can monitor text changes + others

    // Search is now just presenting a view controller. As such, normal view controller
    // presentation semantics apply. Namely that presentation will walk up the view controller
    // hierarchy until it finds the root view controller or one that defines a presentation context.
    //
    self.definesPresentationContext = YES;  // know where you want UISearchController to be displayed

}
```

This is some more code if it can help